# Splash script to retrieve site returns bad body

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to retrieve a number of different URLs using Splash. I am posting to the /execute endpoint a script that looks like this:

```
local request_headers= { 
  ["Accept-Encoding"]           = "gzip, deflate, br",
  ["Accept-Language"]           = "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
  ["Cache-Control"]             = "max-age=0", 
  ["Upgrade-Insecure_Requests"] = "1", 
  ["Accept"]                    = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
  ["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36", 
  ["DNT"] = "1", 
  ["Host"] = "www.douban.com" 
}
splash:go({
  url="https://www.douban.com/people/sophiechou/",
  headers = request_headers
})

return { ok=true, html=splash:html(), info=splash:har() }
```

The HAR must be returned to the the real headers received between the Splash server and the end destination.

So, the problem is that the HTML I receive is likely gzipped compressed. As I understand from Splash, when I return the hash, it automatically JSON encodes it... which JSON encodes the binary gzip, which essentially turns it all into garbage.

Sometimes the sites will return HTML. Sometimes, they will return a Gzip or Defalte or BR.

Why am I not just using "identity"? Many sites we've found do not respond well to identity, either not responding at all, or returning a Forbidden. Changing the encoding both reduces the uniqueness of our browser's footprint, and the number of random problems.

Except that we can't read the page.

It seems like we need to detect, and handle the binary if it's there, through some sort of treat.as_binary(x), or something.. but the documentation is getting REALLY light on how to do this.

This has been stumping me for weeks.  Help! Any thoughts?

P.s. Link to what the html looks like that's returned via a Splash Jupyter notebook. 
[Link](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAHBqNSmnapP5Ks9rD3n9m4Ejy9BSqBIeCE)